# How to change "Compile with" option for Android app

Tags: android

I have application created with "Compile with" option set to API 19. Now when I try to run the app for API level set to 15 or below, I am getting errors. Errors say it is not able to find few attributes, which I guess due to downgrade of API, it is not able to identify few attributes.

So, is there any way through which I can run my app with lower versions of APIs?
How can I change "compile with" option already set while creating the app?

Answer (score 0):

The "compile with" SDK definitions depends on your build tools. For Eclipse/ADT it's defined in `project.properties`.

However, you can really keep it at SDK 19. Instead, set the `minSdkVersion` in your manifest to the minimum SDK version you want to support. Run Android Lint on your project - it will report errors where you're using an API feature not available in your min SDK version.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.
Yes it is reporting error which says few attributes need to be defined.
I cross checked and those attributes are already defined.

Comment: If there's a specific problem, consider including it in your question.

Comment: I want to know how can I change "Compile with" option once application project is created.